# Does $f(\partial A)=\partial f(A)$ for $A\subset \mathbb R^n$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $$\Sigma=\{\sigma (u,v)\mid (u,v)\in [a,b]\times [c,d]\}.$$
I denote $\partial A$ the boundary of the set $A$. Let $$\Gamma_1=\{\sigma (u,c)\mid u :a\to b\}$$
$$\Gamma_2=\{\sigma (b,v)\mid v:c\to d\}$$
$$\Gamma_3= \{\sigma (u,d)\mid u: b\to a\}$$
$$\Gamma_4=\{\sigma (a,v)\mid v:d\to c\}.$$

Let $\mathcal J$ the set of indice $i$ s.t. $\Gamma_i$ is either a singleton or there is $j$ s.t. $\Gamma_i=-\Gamma_j$ . Then, I know that $$\partial \Sigma=\bigcup_{i\in\{1,2,3,4\}\backslash \mathcal J}\Gamma_i.$$

In other word, we have that $$\sigma \Big(\partial ([a,b]\times [c,d])\Big)\subset \partial \sigma ([a,b]\times [c,d]).$$

My questino is : for an unspecified set $A\subset \mathbb R^n$, and a function $f\in \mathcal C^1(A,\mathbb R^m)$ is it a common result that $$f(\partial  A)\subset \partial f(A)\ \ ?$$
and if no, why does it work here ?

Comment: Normally we use $\overline{A}$ for closure and $\partial A$ for boundary

Comment: As @User1006 said. Please stick to standard notation whenever there is one, else it gets very confusing.

Comment: Yes sorry, I wanted to say the boundary. @DanielRobert-Nicoud

Comment: What is $\sigma(u,v)$ and what means notation like $u:a\to b$?